# The gradient in different dimensions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I study to final exam in calc 3.

Question: Are my thoughts about the gradient correct?

The gradient is a normal vector to a plane given a point in $xyz$-plane. With this vector you can calculate the equation for the tangent plane.

If I have a curve $f(x)$, I can consider this as a level curve for a function $f(x,y)$.

If I take the gradient of $f(x,y)$ I will get a 2-dim vector that is orthogonal to the level curve. But the level curve is $f(x)$.

If I was given a point $(x_0)$ and my task is to calculate the tangent line in that point. I can just consider $f(x_0)$ as a level curve on $f(x_0,f(x_0))$, take the gradient to get the normal vector for the tangent line. With equation $ax +by +C =0$ I will get the equation for the tangent line.

The gradient is always  one dimension lower than the actual function.

Regards

Comment: I've removed the gradient-flows tag again. Please read the tag-wiki for that the tag is for. In particular, gradient flows are specific objects in mathematics that are not the same as gradients. Please do not re-add that tag to this question.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The gradient is a trivial case of the Jacobian and is only applicable to functions of the form $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, that is, real-valued functions. Specifically, the gradient is computed as $$\nabla f=\left\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}, \cdots, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\right\rangle$$

It should also be noted that there is no such concept as the "dimension" of a function. You can talk about the dimension of the domain, the dimension of the image, the rank of the derivative, and other similar concepts.

A level curve, more generally a level set, is the pre-image of some constant with respect to a real-valued function and is commonly denoted $g^{-1}(c)$ where $g$ is said continuous function and $c$ is a constant.

It *is* true that the gradient at a point gives the vector orthogonal to the level set at that point and can be used to determine and/or verify a tangent vector at said point.